# CKComponent handle tap gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, componentkit

Is it possible to have an CKComponent without an view to handle a tap gesture?

I just found this solution WITH a view:

```
...

+ (instancetype)newWithViewModel:(NewsComponentViewModel *)viewModel
{
    CKComponent *comp = ...;
    return [super
            newWithView:{
                [UIView class],
                {CKComponentTapGestureAttribute(@selector(didTapView))}
            }
            component:comp];
}
```

Comment: No, since you have to have a view to attach a `UIGestureRecognizer` to. Otherwise you would have to attach to the superview, which is likely not confining the hotspot to the area you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@itsthejb is correct. You must have a view to handle actions.